# Existence claims in the form of arbitrarily large/ small X

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Let $x,q,p \in \Bbb Z^+$
Let $p$ be the number of iterations of a function $f^p(x)$; and
Let $q$ be the number of iterations of a function $f^q(x)$; and
$q<p$

Given a conjecture along the lines of $\forall x:\ f^p(x)=2$. and;
Given an existence claim $\exists x:$ $\displaystyle \lim_{q \to \infty^-}$$f^q(x)=x\cdot2^q$
That is there exists an $x$ such that given an iterative function $f^q(x)$. $x$ can be picked in such a way that it can be made to grow arbitrarily large and we can always find another $x$ such that this is always satisfied.

If this could be proved would this be sufficient as an existence claim against the for all conjecture?

If yes/ no could you explain why and also point me to any articles/ text books I can read on existence claims of this form (that is arbitrarily large/ small etc.)

Apologies if this is slightly vague or if any incorrect notation has been used.

Comment: The $q$ in $\lim_{q\to\infty}f^q(x)$ and the $q$ in $x\cdot 2^q$ cannot logically be the same thing. Please alter your notation to clarify what you mean.

Comment: Hi @DanielWainfleet truly apologies for my ignorance but I do not see why they cannot logically be the same thing.

For example:\
Let the variable $q=5$\
$f^q(x) = f^5(x)\approx x\cdot2^5$; or

Let the variable $q=9$\
$f^q(x) = f^9(x)\approx x\cdot2^9$;


$\displaystyle \lim_{q \to 5}f^q(x)\approx x\cdot2^5$

$\displaystyle \lim_{q \to 9}f^q(x)\approx x\cdot2^9$

Why then can't it be the case that:\
$\displaystyle \lim_{q \to \infty}$$f^q(x)=x\cdot2^q$

Comment: ??? What do you think $\lim_{q\to\infty}$ means?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet - as $q$ approaches value from +/-, so more precisely I should have written $\displaystyle \lim_{q \to \infty^-}$$f^q(x)=x\cdot2^q$